# In PostgreSQL, are all expressions in ORDER BY clause evaluated?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm looking to optimise a PostgreSQL query of mine and couldn't find anything on the internal workings of the query planner when it comes to ORDER BY.

Consider the following PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY rank, ST_Distance(geom1, geom2)
```

Is `ST_Distance(geom1, geom2)` calculated for all rows in `mytable`, even where `rank` is unique?

This is *not* a postgis question. `ST_Distance(geom1, geom2)` could be any expression that requires (expensive) computations.

Comment: If rank is unique, what's the point of adding additional expressions to the ORDER BY?

Comment: It's *possible* that the query optimizer might be clever enough to check unique constraints on the column and disregard any additional order-by clauses. however if you just happen to  know the data is unique it still has to evaluate the full order-by since the query execution plan cannot know in advance what data it's going to find; you could easily test this though.

Comment: I would suggest that you simulate the case. Write a dummy function that raises a notice of its arguments; Give it a high cost like 1000; Write/run a query like yours that orders by a field and that function instead of `ST_Distance` then see what happens.

Comment: Good question. Test it by creating both indexes `(rank)` and  `(rank, (ST_Distance(geom1, geom2)))` and then by retrieving the execution plan. See which index is used.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I didn't mean unique as in the column constraint. I was just referring to any number of values of `rank` being unique, not all of them necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are evaluated.  PostgreSQL's sort projects all the expressions it needs to do the comparison up front and stores the results.  It does not defer the expression evaluation until there is a tie to break.